# Is there a way to see the list iterated over in a for-loop?

Tags: for-loop, zsh

I have problems with a `for`-loop in a zsh-script. It seg-faults just when it is ending.

I have inserted `echo`-statements just before and after `done`and the one before is printed (multiple times, as the loop executes) but the second never appears, instead the seg-fault happens.

The list is generated by a non-trivial command-substitution.
I tried a trivial loop with the same list-generator and just an `echo` of the loop-variable as the body and that works fine, no seg-fault. It also shows that there is no spurious element at the end of the list.

It still seems to be something with reaching the end of the word list of the `for`-loop but I have no idea where to continue my investigating. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial loop doing fine indicates that there is nothing wrong with the list-generator, that causes the error on its own.

As the original loop also prints every (expected) `echo` except the one after the loop, something has to go wrong between the last last element and the end of the loop. The only reason anything will between that last `echo` in the loop and the one following the loop is, if the loop is not finished, which only happens if there are more elements in the word list.

So, most likely there *is* a spurious element at the end of the list, but it is not (easily) visible with just an `echo`. For example `\b`:

```
prompt% for a in a b c; do echo $a; done
a
b
c
prompt% for a in a b c '\b'; do echo $a; done
a
b
c
prompt%
```

To make sure you do not miss anything, you could pipe the output of `echo` to `hexdump -C`.

```
prompt% for a in a b c '\b'; do echo $a | hexdump -C ;done
00000000  61 0a                                             |a.|
00000002
00000000  62 0a                                             |b.|
00000002
00000000  63 0a                                             |c.|
00000002
00000000  08 0a                                             |..|
00000002
prompt%
```